# Matriz 4x4 em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Como eu posso fazer a matriz 4x4 conter números de 1 a 8 em duplicidade (isso é um par de 1(1,1), 1 par de 2(2,2)..) e esses números serem distribuídos aleatoriamente.

Pensei em usar choice ou sample do módulo random mas não sei como

Meu código por enquanto está assim

```
matriz = []
for y in range(4):
    linha = []
    for x in range(4):
        linha.append(0)
        
    matriz.append(linha)

return matriz
```

Retorno esperado:

```
[[5, 7, 5, 6], [7, 1, 4, 4], [8, 2, 3, 6], [3, 2, 1, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode começar criando uma lista com os números de 1 a 8:

```
>>> list(range(1,9))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

A partir então obtenha uma lista com esses elementos duplicados:

```
>>> list(range(1,9)) * 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Embaralhe a lista com o método [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> lista = sample((list(range(1,9)) * 2), k=16)   #Cada chamada gera um valor diferente.
[7, 8, 5, 3, 8, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6]
```

Finalmente obtendo a matriz desejada:

```
>>> [lista[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(lista), 4)]
[[7, 8, 5, 3], [8, 1, 4, 6], [2, 4, 7, 3], [2, 5, 1, 6]]
```

Juntando num exemplo:

```
from random import sample

lista = sample((list(range(1,9)) * 2), k=16)
matriz = [lista[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(lista), 4)]
print(matriz)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/RandMatrix#main.py)</sup>

Ou ainda o mesmo exemplo usando [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) para embaralhar a lista internamente.

```
from random import shuffle

lista = list(range(1,9)) * 2
shuffle(lista)
matriz = [lista[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(lista), 4)]
print(matriz)
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/RandMatrix2#main.py)</sup>

Comment: muito obrigada!!